# Find all Jordan canonical forms of 2 x 2, 3 x 3 and 4 x 4 matrices over C.

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, matrix-decomposition

Can someone walk me through understanding this question/solution to it? On the one hand, I'm thinking something simple like (for the $2 \times 2$ case):

\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha & 1 \\
    0 & \beta \\
\end{bmatrix}

and

\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha & 0 \\
    0 & \beta \\
\end{bmatrix}

Since there's no other way to be in JCF for a $2 \times 2$ matrix. On the other hand, this seems to naive.

Comment: Your answer for the $2\times 2$ case is incorrect, but it's not much more complicated. It's wrong because of the first one.What happens when $\alpha \neq\beta$?

Comment: You've almost got it. Is $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 5 & 1 \\ 0 & 3\end{array}\right]$ in JCF?

Comment: It's not. I see, so only the second matrix I wrote is valid?

Comment: The second is valid, but you need to modify the first. For example, $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 5 & 1 \\ 0 & 5 \end{array}\right]$ is in JCF.

Answer (score 3):

In the following, $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ $\gamma,$ $\delta$ do not necessarily represent distinct eigenvalues. Jordan blocks can be permuted, so the second three-by-three and last four-by-four matrices below each have two permutations, and the second four-by-four matrix has three permutations. I assume that you are interested only in the structure of the Jordan blocks; otherwise, there are more permutations to consider by permuting the order of the eigenvalues.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0\\
0 & \beta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1\\
0 & \alpha
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0\\
0 & \beta & 0\\
0 & 0 & \gamma\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0\\
0 & \beta & 1\\
0 & 0 & \beta\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1 & 0\\
0 & \alpha & 1\\
0 & 0 & \alpha\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \beta & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \gamma & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \delta\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \beta & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \gamma & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \gamma\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \alpha & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \beta & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \beta\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \beta & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \beta & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \beta\\
\end{bmatrix}$$